# how can i extract text after hash # in the href part from a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following a tags:

```
<a href="#tab1">Any tab1 Label</a>
<a href="#tab2">tab2 Label</a>
<a href="#tab3">Any tab3 Label</a>
<script>
function tellMyName()
{
    alert(this.href);
}

</script>
```

Now i want to bind the tellMyName function to all the a tags and get **tab1** if **Any tab1 Label** is clicked, **tab2** if **tab2 Label** is clicked and so on...

Comment: One more thing I have noticed..I think you have to use  <a href="#tab1" onclick="tellMyName()
">Any tab1 Label</a> and so on....

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
function tellMyName() {
  alert(this.hash.substr(1));
}

$('a').click(tellMyName);
```

Comment: if should be this.hash.substr(1)

Comment: I used location.hash

Answer (score 25):

```
function tellMyName() {
    var str = this.href.split("#")[1];
    alert(str);
}
```

Not all the time only the hash part will be displayed on the link. Sometimes the Host is added to the `href`.  By splitting the href with the `hash` (#) and get the second part of the split string, you'll get what you want.

Comment: yup its returning the correct one as i am searching... thnx and binding has been working as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861076/how-can-i-extract-text-after-hash-in-the-href-part-from-a-tag/3861095#3861095

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this

```
var fragment = $('a#my-link')[0].hash.substr(1);
```

[Check it out.](http://jsbin.com/iroqe3/edit)

Answer (score 2):

```
function tellMyName() {
  alert(this.hash.replace('#',''));
}

$('a').click(tellMyName);
```

## [crazy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaRwy/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function tellMyName() {
    var str = this.prop("hash").substr(1)
    alert(str);
}

this.prop("hash") will return the hash value i.e #tab1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function tellMyName()
{
    var text = this.href;
    text = text.replace("#","");
    alert(text);
}

</script>
```

Comment: as suggested below, you have to bind this function to anchor tag. i.e. $('a').click(tellMyName);

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<a href="#tab1">Any tab1 Label</a>
<a href="#tab2">tab2 Label</a>
<a href="#tab3">Any tab3 Label</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(){
alert(this.hash.split('#')[1]); //This will alert # part in clicked anchor tag
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
...
var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
$(activeTab).fadeIn();
...
```

This use href="#tab-id" for locate #tab-id element you want, and fade in.