# Get string after the sign #

Tags: jquery, match

How can I get the string after the sign #:

```
// get current url
var url      = window.location.href;
// output: //http://www.test.com/Tests/pagination.php?page=4#tab2
alert(url);
```

How can I get the name tab2 which is after #

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861076/how-can-i-extract-text-after-hash-in-the-href-part-from-a-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
window.location.hash
```

> Return the anchor part of a URL. Assume that the current URL is
>   http://www.example.com/test.htm#part2: #part2
>
> The Window.location read-only property returns a Location object with information about the current location of the document.
>   Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with
>   location as if it were a string in most cases: location =
>   'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of location.href =
>   'http://www.example.com'.

More Read [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Answer (score 2):

```
location.hash.replace("#","")
```

should do the trick