# trying to pass $this.attr("href") to fadeIn to reveal hidden div content using ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a jquery fade in, to hide and activate certain div elements for each page similar to a tabbed interface. I can't tell if its because I have a div within a div (that div formats my html right of a navigation bar) or not. I have tried changing my css and query to $("tabs>div>div:visible") but that does not work as well. It was different from my reference because it is not in the same div class and underlying id as the reference links and anchor tags.

**HTML**

```js
$('#sidetabs>ul>li>a').click(function() {
  $('#sidetabs>ul>li>a').css({
    color: 'white'
  });
  $(this).css({
    color: 'darkorange'
  });
  const thisTab = $(this).attr("href");

  $('#tabs>div:visible').fadeOut(200, function() {
    $(thisTab.fadeIn(200));
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

#sidetabs {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#sidetabs>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidenav a {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: darkorange;
}

#sidetabs>div {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #EAEAEA;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

#tabs>div {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #EAEAEA;
}

#tabs>div:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}

#sidetabs>ul>li:first-of-type a {
  color: darkorange;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tab Interface...</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidetabs" class="sidenav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#clients">clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#OSU">contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div id="tabs" class="main">
    <div id="about">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>This is an about section about my company</p>
      <p>This is what I am about</p>
    </div>

    <div id="services">
      <h1>Services</h1>
      <p>This is an about section about my services company</p>
      <p>This is what we are about</p>
    </div>

    <div id="clients">
      <h1>Clients</h1>
      <p>These are the people that I have helped.</p>
      <p>They were happy with my service.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="OSU">
      <h1>Open Source University</h1>
      <p>These are my credentials from using open source content.</p>
      <p>Look at me learn.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You missed a ending parenthesis: `$(thisTab.fadeIn(200));` => `$(thisTab).fadeIn(200));` Also, you should just use `this.hash` rather than `href`; browsers often replace `href` with the fully-qualified URL. I'm sure we have a duplicate question about that somewhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i extract text after hash # in the href part from a tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861076/how-can-i-extract-text-after-hash-in-the-href-part-from-a-tag)

Comment: You can do this with CSS only though, using [the `:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)...

Comment: It seems (thisTab).fadeIn(200); did the trick. Thanks Heretic Monkey!